# UITableViewCell editing one cell changes another cell controls after 8 rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

now I a beginner in IOS programming, I created a view and placed a tableview inside it, then I created a xib with the template I want to use for the tablecell and made a class for that call. the table cell has a label (set on load of the cell), a switch and a textfield.

The table loads fine, with the labels showing the correct text they should, there is 12 rows that are loaded from the database. sqLite.

the problem:
when I edit the textfield in row 1, the text field in row 9 is edited, and vise versa. when I edit in row 2, row 10 is edited! upto row 4,12 not only the text field, but also toggling the switch toggles.

Some code:
AlertViewController.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
```

AlertViewController.m

```
@synthesize table;

static NSString *alertCellID=@"AlertViewCell";

----some code here ----
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
---some code here----
    self.table.delegate=self;
    self.table.dataSource=self;

    if(managedObjectContext==nil)
    {
        id appDelegate=(id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        managedObjectContext=[appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    [self loadCategories];

    [table registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"AlertViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:alertCellID];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrCategories count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Category *cat=[arrCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    AlertViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:alertCellID];
    UILabel *lblGroupName=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    lblGroupName.text=cat.nameEn;
    UITextField *txtHours=(UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
    txtHours.delegate=self;
    return cell;
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

**Edit:**
I dont know is it related to the scroll size fitting 8 records? and how to overcome that?

Comment: Please edit your post to indent your code properly.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your `UITextFieldDelegate` methods (like `textFieldDidChange:` and `textFieldDidEndEditing:` and `textFieldShouldReturn:`).

Comment: that should not cause this effect, as its also effecting the switches... now when I changed the creation of the cells to not reuse cell, that effect was gone, but when ever the textfields are out of viewable area their values are lost.

Comment: I, too, would like to see your text delegate methods; I'd want to see the logic that takes values from the text field after editing and updates the model array.

Comment: oh I didnt do that yet, I m working on that now, after I have solved the issue, I will be able to post how I solved it in 53 minutes.

Comment: but in case you want to know how I m dealing with the data now, I tag the superview of the textfield with the row number, and on the fielddidfinishediting I check if the superview is of the type of my cell view, and according to that I deal with the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved it as follows:

First the issue was because i m using dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier, which seems to return the same reference every x number of rows, where x is the number of rows that appear on the screen without scrolling, so this made cell 1=cell 9, cell 2=cell 10 and so on.

so to solve it, I had to make the identifier unique, and to solve the issue that the identifier was used to load the registered nib, I had to register the nib with this unique identifier names.. here is the changes:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",alertCellID,indexPath.row];
    [table registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"AlertViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:identifier];
    Category *cat=[arrCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    AlertViewCell *cell = (AlertViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!cell)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AlertViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    UILabel *lblGroupName=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    lblGroupName.text=cat.nameEn;
    UITextField *txtHours=(UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
    txtHours.delegate=self;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: this is a very bad solution. the tableview uses cell re-usage for a reason.

Comment: I think you are right, I have been thinking it as viewstate for web applications. but it seems that on ios I should immediately save and immediately load data... but the top solution should also not be a problem for small amount of rows... 12 in my case